# Получение reCaptcha Android

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase, recaptcha

Пытаюсь получить reCaptcha для отправки на сервер Firebase. Прочитал [тут](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha#kotlin), имплементировал Executor, написал такое в onClick.

```
override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        SafetyNet.getClient(this).verifyWithRecaptcha("Здесь я прописал мой API Key")
            .addOnSuccessListener(this as Executor, OnSuccessListener { response ->
                val userResponseToken = response.tokenResult
                Log.d("TAG", userResponseToken.toString())
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this as Executor, OnFailureListener { e ->
                if (e is ApiException) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Error: ${CommonStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(e.statusCode)}")
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "Error: ${e.message}")
            })
```

Логи не выводятся. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: А хоть где нибудь выводятся логи? В onCreate активити например?

Comment: Да, другие логи выводится

Comment: Кода мало, можно только гадать. А onClick() срабатывает? А в манифесте разрешение есть на интернет?

Comment: onClick работает, в манифесте USES PERMISSION INTERNET. По поводу что кода мало, чтобы вам еще хотелось увидеть?

Comment: Ну смотри, я не знаю твой уровень знаний в разработке на андроид. Может ты слушатель не привязал в вьюхе, или привязал на задизэйблил. Чем больше тем - меньше вопросов.

Comment: `override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phonenumber)
    textLimitError = findViewById(R.id.textLimitError)
    next = findViewById(R.id.enter)
    next.setOnClickListener(this)
    editNumber = findViewById(R.id.numInput)
    editNumber.setOnKeyListener(this)
}`
В onClick после попытки получить капчу  перехожу на следующую активити, если введен корректный номер телефона в эдит текст. Также переопределены ф-ии onKey(для обработки ввода номера телефона), dispatchTouchEvent и execute (пустая)

Comment: Еще может быть, что эта гугл из за санкций блочет трафик. МНогие сервисы гугла счас работают плохо/не работают. Можно попробовать через ВПН все тоже самое сделать

Comment: Подключил VPN, теперь по нажатию открывается окно капчи, но логи все еще не выводятся. В логах ошибок нашел такое: **android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: pending_ops.tag, pending_ops.target_class, pending_ops.target_package, pending_ops.user_id (code 2067 SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_UNIQUE)** . Там ошибка подлиннее, но не влазит в комментарий. И еще от gms выводит **I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: RecaptchaMFrame is not defined", source: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/mframe (1).** Все это чуть позже нажатия выводится

Comment: Как мне кажется логи сработают по факту валидации капчи - успешно/не успешно. Пробовал пройти ее? А на эти ошибки думаю можно забить

Comment: Подключается капча v3, она автоматически проходит, идет загрузка в диалоговом окне, а потом скрывается. Вроде логи стоят и в OnSuccessListener, и в OnFailureListener, поэтому какие-то из них в любом случае должны выводится

Comment: Не знаю про реКапчу, но вообще еще таска может быть отменена, и это третье состояние, помимо успеха - неудачи. А на verifyWithRecaptcha() нельзя повешать что нибудь вроде onCanselesListener() или onComplitListener()?

Comment: Добавил 
`.addOnCanceledListener { Log.d("My", "cancel"); }
            .addOnCompleteListener(this as Executor, OnCompleteListener { Log.d("My", "complete"); })`
Все еще ничего не выводится

Comment: Это уже странно. Я бы все таки исключил глюки с logkat, и проверил слушатели таски дебагом или тостиками. Ну и попробовать отменить таску - закрыть окно капчи, тогда onCancel же должен отработать..

Comment: Проходился с дебагом, не в один из методов не заходит, при этом там какие-то странные поля и ф-ии, в стиле zza zzb zze zzf и т.п.. Очень непонятно сделаны их классы

Comment: @Михаил я опустил версию 
`com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:16.0.0:16.0.0`
До 16, такой же как макс. версия 
`com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-safetynet:16.0.0`
Теперь срабатывает onFailure и в Log выводится *Error: API_NOT_CONNECTED*

Comment: Ни какой обратной совместимости у них), есть ошибка уже неплохо - можно попробовать полазить в классах либы (хотя наверно там мало что можно почерпнуть). В доках гуглятся статус коды SafetyNetStatusCodes https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/CommonStatusCodes#API_NOT_CONNECTED , там даже что то предлагают по причинам

Comment: Оказывается что с эмуляторов нельзя запускать рекапчу, она не сработает без гугл серсисес. Запустил с телефона отладку, теперь ошибка 12007, не верный sitekey. Пробовал тот что у всего проекта в firebase и тот что в google-services.json, не подходят